# Apache netbeans file explorer slow response

Tags: java, file, debugging, netbeans

Every time I open the file explorer of netbeans, it's always give me the slow performance. About 1 month ago this problems is not here, what should i do to fix it? it always take a long time, even when i try to open my project or something that needs file explorer to do so. I used apache netbeans 15 IDE, on Win 11 x64.

I expect my java netbeans is back to it's normal performance like before, it's really frustrating! pls help me! i searched on google many times but they said i need to delete broken links to fix it, i don't know how to do it, what should i do to delete that broken links and what the kind of large zip file i should remove?

Comment: Something that is easy to do is: [1] First close/stop as many external Windows applications/processes as possible to ensure that the performance issue is not caused by something other than NetBeans (e.g. Windows 11 Antimalware Service). [2] Close all NetBeans projects. [3] Restart NetBeans. [4] Reopen your projects one by one to see if you can identify any specific project that provokes the slow response. That approach won't resolve your problem, but if there is specific project causing performance problems you can focus on that one, and update your question with additional information.

Comment: I came across this problem myself this week where opening any file in the NB filer interface took over a minute. NB showed text in the filer box: "Dialog seems to be slow, probably because of JDK bug. Please upgrade JDK, remove zip files from Desktop folder or run system with `-J-Dnb.FileChooser.useShellFolder=false` property." Removing any zips didn't resolve the issue but when I added that property to the `...\Netbeans-<xx>\netbeans\etc\netbeans.conf` file at the end of `netbeans_default_options` it suddenly came back instantly. I'm using Netbeans 20.